# Как передать webdriver selenium в декоратор Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, allure

В своих тестах я использую конструкцию:

```
try:
    self.assertTrue(page.logo.is_displayed())
except:
    allure.attach(self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), 'screenshot')
    raise
```

И задался вопросом закинуть в декоратор try... except...

Что то в этом роде:

```
def ErrorScreenShot(function_to_decorate):
    def ExceptionProcess(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            function_to_decorate(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), 'screenshot')
            raise

    return ExceptionProcess

@ErrorScreenShot
def VerifyEqual(a, b, comment="Actual and expected results aren't equal"):
    assert a == b, comment
```

Чтобы при вызове функции:

```
VerifyEqual(1, 3, "1 не равно 3")
```

Получить скрин и `AssertError: "1 не равно 3"`

Но тут дилемма как передать в декоратор selenium driver, который используется в тестовом коде?

Comment: вы можете context manager   вместо этого создать: `with screenshot_on_error(self.driver): self.assertTrue(page.logo.is_displayed())` где `screen_shot_on_error()` [можно с помощью `contextlib.contextmanager` определить.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)

Answer (score 0):

Если декоратор только к методам нужно применять:

```
@screenshot_on_failure
def test_something(self):
    self.assertTrue(page.logo.isdisplayed())
```

тогда первый аргумент всегда `self`:

```
def screenshot_on_failure(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            # use self.driver here
            raise
    return wrapper
```